# babel-loader error - TypeError: val is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm trying to use webpack and babel and I'm getting errors that don't appear to be anywhere online. It's very simple js right now while I test and it still gives me errors on places that it shouldn't.

```js
var test = () => {
  console.log("Test")
}
test()
```

I'm getting the error:

```
ERROR in ./dist/main.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
TypeError: val is not a function

ERROR in ./dist/main.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
TypeError: val is not a function
    at cache.using (C:\Users\Bacon\Desktop\ReactProj\jsx\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\caching.js:179:47)
    at CacheConfigurator.using (C:\Users\Bacon\Desktop\ReactProj\jsx\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\caching.js:132:17)
    at Object.cacheFn [as cache] (C:\Users\Bacon\Desktop\ReactProj\jsx\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\caching.js:179:18)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\Bacon\Desktop\ReactProj\jsx\babel.config.js:2:9)
    at readConfigJS (C:\Users\Bacon\Desktop\ReactProj\jsx\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\files\configuration.js:212:15)
    at cachedFunction (C:\Users\Bacon\Desktop\ReactProj\jsx\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\caching.js:33:19)
    at readConfig (C:\Users\Bacon\Desktop\ReactProj\jsx\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\files\configuration.js:173:56)    at findRootConfig (C:\Users\Bacon\Desktop\ReactProj\jsx\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\files\configuration.js:148:16)
    at buildRootChain (C:\Users\Bacon\Desktop\ReactProj\jsx\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-chain.js:78:44)
    at loadPrivatePartialConfig (C:\Users\Bacon\Desktop\ReactProj\jsx\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\partial.js:85:55)
    at Object.loadPartialConfig (C:\Users\Bacon\Desktop\ReactProj\jsx\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\partial.js:110:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Bacon\Desktop\ReactProj\jsx\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:140:26)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (C:\Users\Bacon\Desktop\ReactProj\jsx\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:3:103)
    at _next (C:\Users\Bacon\Desktop\ReactProj\jsx\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:5:194)
    at C:\Users\Bacon\Desktop\ReactProj\jsx\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:5:364
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Bacon\Desktop\ReactProj\jsx\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:5:97)
    at Object._loader (C:\Users\Bacon\Desktop\ReactProj\jsx\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:220:18)
    at Object.loader (C:\Users\Bacon\Desktop\ReactProj\jsx\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:56:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Bacon\Desktop\ReactProj\jsx\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:51:12)
```

There's no val anywhere in my code, so I don't see where it's going wrong. Here's my devDependencies in my project.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.3.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.3.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.4",
    "@babel/preset-es2015": "^7.0.0-beta.53",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "standard": "^12.0.1",
    "webpack": "^4.29.5",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.3"
  }
```

I've been trying to figure this out for a few hours to no avail and I'm going insane not being able to find it on google.

Comment: Since you haven't included the stack trace for the error, this is currently unanswerable.

Comment: Just added the rest of the stacktrace. Doesn't seem particularly useful to me.

Comment: The stack trace mentions `jsx\babel.config.js` which is calling a function that then throws, so most likely your config us calling a function in an incorrect way. If you include the `babel.config.js` content, I can tell you what is wrong.

Comment: I just looked into it and found that the `app.cache()` didn't have any value in the parentheses. I set it to `true` and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

In `babel.config.js`, I set the parameter of `app.cache()` to `true` and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `babel.config.js` instead of `.babelrc` and you have this:

```
module.exports = api => {
  api.cache();

  return {
    ...
  }
}
```

`cache` requires a boolean argument. So either pass `true` or `false` into `cache()` like so: `api.cache(true);`